# Using alias for endpoints with Node and Sails.JS?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, alias, endpoint

Is there a way to make aliases for endpoints in Node?

I have a current endpoint like the following:

```
sails.router.bind('/current_url/items/:itemId/', itemController.getItem, 'get', {});
```

A different endpoint is needed that will give the same response. Do we have to create a new route like this? :

```
sails.router.bind('/new_url/items/:itemId/', itemController.getItem, 'get', {});
```

Or is there a way to make aliases referring to the previous one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back at the question seems that in case of needing 2 different endpoints calling at the same method, the cleaner and more easy to read solution in node would be to write both of them.